# Error twitter API with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I have the following node js code

---

```
var http= require('http').createServer();
 var util = require('util');
var twitter=require('ntwitter');

http.listen(3000);

var twit= new twitter({
consumer_key: 'consumer_key',
consumer_secret: 'consumer_secret',
access_token_key: 'access_token_key',
access_token_secret: 'access_token_secret'
});


console.log('Connected to twittere');

twit.stream(
    'statuses/filter',
    { track: ['awesome', 'cool', 'rad', 'gnarly', 'groovy'] },
    function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
            console.log(tweet.text);
        });
    }
);

console.log('after Connected');
```

---

after executing the code i get error as :

$ node twitter1
Connected to twittere
after Connected

events.js:74
        throw TypeError('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');

```
          ^
```

TypeError: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.

```
at TypeError (<anonymous>)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:74:15)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/atishshinde/Documents/RIT/GIS/node_modules/ntwitter/lib/twitter.js:251:14)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1688:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1583:20)
at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:507:12)
at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
```

i am not sure what is going wrong here?

Its a simple code .. Please suggest..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you received an error response and not the tweet object like you were expecting. Log the tweet Onsted of tweet.text and see what it says